# Suppose that $X=C_1\cup C_2$ where each $C_i$ is homeomorphic to the topologist sin curve. Can $X$ be path connected

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X=C_1\cup C_2$ where each $C_i$ is homeomorphic to the topologist sin curve.  Can $X$ be path connected?

So, we know that the topologist's sin curve is not path connected because there is no path from the origin to anywhere else on the graph $y = \sin (1/x)$ for $x \in (0,1]$.

I was told $X$ is path connected, but I don't see how and I definitely don't know how t prove it.

Comment: It seems the answer must be yes.  $X$ need not necessarily be path connected, but it might be.  Take for example the topologists sin curve as usual and then take a second one, to the second one reflect about the $y$-axis and add one. Then union with the first one.  That should do it, no?

Comment: How does this get a path from the origin to somewhere else on the graph?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I'm pretty sure that should work; that was my second thought (after one which in hindsight obviously doesn't work).

Comment: I don't see how we fix the problem with the origin.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "add one?"

Comment: @Michael By "add one" I meant shift the entire thing to the right by one unit.  In the union you then can get to the vertical line in the first space, that's usually isolated, by traveling along the sin curve of the second space - and conversely.  Perhaps a picture will help, I'll try to make one.

Comment: @Michael I'll try to explain Gregory Grant's idea a little better. Take The topologist sin curve $C_1$. Take another copy, reflect it around the $y$ axis and move it to the right by $1/2\pi$, and call this new curve $C_2$. The origin of the curve $C_1$ is now inside $C_2$ and vice-versa, and there are lots of other intersection points between these curves. So we can start from, say, the origin of $C_1$, walk around the "curved part" of $C_2$ and get to the "curved part" of $C_1$, etc...

Comment: Oh! I see!  I wasn't getting the shift over to the right part earlier.  That makes sense.

Comment: @Michael I'm glad you got it because I'm not having much luck drawing it...